# How is the Android WifiManager connected to wpa_supplicant?

Tags: android, service, wifi, cyanogenmod

I would like to restrict to Wifi networks a user can choose from on Android (Cyanogenmod). One approach I though of is filtering the networks on the service level. However, I can't find how the WifiManager is bound to wpa_supplicant. so my questions are:

1. How is the Java Wifi-Stack connected with wpa_supplicant?
2. Any other ideas on how to restrict the Wifi networks for an Android tablet user?

Answer to question 1 would generally help me to understand how Android services are bound to linux services.

**UPDATE:**

Digging more into the Android code, I found the real questions are:

- Where do I find the implementation of IWifiManager?
- Where is WifiManager instanciated by the system?

Comment: Are you trying to make your own ROM based on cyanogenmod?

Comment: Yes, that's correct David.

Answer (score 2):

> How is the Java Wifi-Stack connected with wpa_supplicant?

In the "good old Android time", the Java relied on some JNI  to communicate with `wpa_supplicant` using a pair of local sockets (file descriptors) to communicate in textual form with it. Writing/reading via `select()` on the file des'. Once you have a `wpa_supplicant` running (or `hostapd)`, provided you configured these correctly you have a local socket that you can select/read/write commands and get results from.

See here for some explanations about it:

https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html

You can experiment with this by yourself using the `wpa_cli` or `hostapd_cli` programs on your PC, that do just that: send commands to the daemon, get asynchronous responses, etc loop/rince/repeat. For wpa sup' use its `-C = ctrl_interface parameter`, and for hostapd use `-g   global control interface` path option, or do that in the respective config file. What you basically get is a kind of shell communicating to the daemons, so it all balls down to creating command strings and parsing strings responses. You may find this is in the `wifi-legacy` or something like that from your Android source tree.

And this was a very pragmatic, simple approach that just worked.

Now, the actual true, long-term solution, correct way to communicate with the kernel Wi-Fi `mac80211/nl80211` layers is through `libnl`. And from what I can see, that's the way Google uses nowadays. **BUT!** B*UT:* it comes with a steep learning curve, because the `libnl` library that is to be used for that is very extensible/generic, which means "complicated to do the most basic thing", and `libnl` came with quite a few API changes. If you're Google, no problem with that, that's a very valuable investment and we will no get around this forever anyway, so go for it, we'll use it everywhere. Use `libnl` to communicate to 802.11 kernel layers, and build some higher level code around that.

If you're a casual user, welcome to a few days (weeks?) to get into `libnl` for 802.11 use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, jbm. However, I was more looking for an explanation of the abstract "WifiManager" get's tied to the concrete implementation of an wrapper to wpa_supplicant. Netlink (libnl) is not used for communication between wpa_supplicant and WifiManager, I guess, but rather for communication with the kernel Wifi stack.

Answer (score 0):

To answer just the code location question, IWifiManager.Stub is implemented in [WifiServiceImpl](http://IWifiManager.Stub%20is%20in%20https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/master/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiServiceImpl.java.). Prior to L, it was in [WifiService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/9158825f9c41869689d6b1786d7c7aa8bdd524ce/services/core/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiService.java).